# Crontab steps are reseted after reload

Tags: cron

Hi guys i am kinda new in managing cron and i have the following doubt. I am setting a crontab that sends a mail every 10 minutes.

```
*/10 * * * * mail xxxxxxx
```

This will send a mail for example:

```
00:00 mail mail xxxxxxx
00:10 mail mail xxxxxxx
00:20 mail mail xxxxxxx
```

If i modify the crontab task at `00:25`

```
*/10 * * * * mail xxxxxxx && echo xxxx
```

Does this modification changes the task time ? for example

```
00:25 mail xxxxxxx && echo xxxx
00:35 mail xxxxxxx && echo xxxx
00:45 mail xxxxxxx && echo xxxx
```

Or still with

```
00:30 mail xxxxxxx && echo xxxx
00:40 mail xxxxxxx && echo xxxx
00:50 mail xxxxxxx && echo xxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, after modification it still to be run an "even" times 30, 40, 50 etc. Cron ignores the time when crontab was modified, and only uses its contents. */10 is 0, 10, 20 etc.

That said, it is possible to use 25,35,45 etc. in a single line, separating minute values. Use it like this:

```
5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * * mail xxxxxxx
```

some versions of cron also allow steps after a range, so following is possible:

```
5-55/10 * * * * main xxxxxxx
```

it is equilvalent to previous variant.

Read man crontab, for example: https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab

And last note. I answered 25 minutes after your question. That's more than enough time to just try everything by yourself!